# Power Pivot change edit connection greyed out

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have a PowerPivot in Excel and I need to edit the connection. The problem is that the connection string seems to be grayed out. I don't see an edit button either.

Any ideas on how I can edit the connection?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to resolve it. This might help someone else.

```
Data> PowerPivot > Get External Data > Existing Connections 
Select the connection and press edit button
Change the path and refresh
```